# ArcGIS geo-trigger geofence service, who uses it?

Tags: push, arcgis, geofencing, arcgis-js-api

I'm researching geo-fencing options for a new app. I need to create geo fences programatically. The options that allows me to do this out there are not in plenty ...

I found ArcGIS geo-trigger service, which seems to do all I need. ArcGIS is well known for GIS services. But I found it strange the lack of buzz around this specific tool.

Is there anyone out there using this service that can help in providing some inside view of it?

Or even alternatives to it ...

Thanks,
Murilo

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any experience with the ArcGIS service, but you might want to check out [Plot Projects](http://www.plotprojects.com). You can send a notification when a user enters, exits or dwells in a geofence or perform any other action using geotriggers. You can create an account for free and test it using demo apps for iOS and Android. Additionally there are wrappers for PhoneGap/Cordova and Appcelerator if you want to write your app in JavaScript.

Disclaimer: I work for Plot Projects as a developer.

Comment: Yep, I've tested Plot Projects with Titanium and indeed is working pretty good. Is a great tool =]